# Publishing a site with Tomcat

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat

I am working on an open source project that written in Java.
I am using Tomcat server,Mysql and Java,
with writing
http://localhost:8080/Projectname,
I can run this project
But I must open this project to other users,
I have a constatnt Id, I have done it with using  IIS before many times.
How can I do it with Tomcat server,
Is there anyone who has experince on this matter

Thanks for your helping

Comment: if they are in your network you can give them : http://yourip:8080/Projectname

Comment: Are these other users on the same network as the system running Tomcat?

Comment: Yes, but I have a constatntId and it is open outside of the newtwork, it is a virtual server.

Answer (score 1):

You Should replace localhost with your IP and check firewall exception for this 8080 port.